# php files not executing on nginx - nginx or php?

Tags: php, nginx

'the problem is when i try to run php files nginx will download php file instead of executing it'

Variations of the above have come up numerous times in forums and on the web over the past few years.
I have that problem.

I've tried a lot of methods to get nginx to execute a php file, including:

using try files/not using try files

checkng and re-checking the file permissions

include fastcgi.conf instead of fastcgi_params

the HttpDavModule vs no HttpDavModule

Commenting out the reload signal USR2

php.ini file = 1 vs 0

TCP vs Unix socket

and of course, clearing the browser cache.

running nginx -t or status, or for that matter the same on php5-fpm - I don't get any errors.

I've tried it on Debian 8 - not work.

I'm now using Ubuntu 15.04 
with the php.info file I get 5.6.4-4ubuntu6.4

You don't seem to be able to get an answer out of Nginx, I tried that too.
The LEMP server works fine - just not with php.

All I'm talking about is a simple Php file like:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="process.php">
```

In this case, I shoould get a number, but I just get the php code itself: i.e.  The number that came up is $result

So I would think it is a Nginx thing, but I seem to recall reading something somewhere about how one had to add a line or two to the php file itself to get it to work in Nginx.

### Anyone know of any solutions that work to this re-curring problem? Nginx or php problem??  Seems to be this would be an easy solution, but....????

The last thing I tried (out of many) was from
http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-install-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-15-04/

The section in question (or not everyone agrees with what goes in here) is

```
location ~ \.php$ {
try_files $uri =404;   ---------> Add this line
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
#       # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
#
#       # With php5-cgi alone:
#       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#       # With php5-fpm:
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;
}
```

Nevertheless, while the LEMP server worked, php files did not execute.

Comment: See above changes.  If you have a LEMP server (Nginx, MariaDB, and Php5-fpm) where you don't have any problem with php scripts, please let me know.  Maye by comparing notes....

Comment: Full config including `include`d files